# How to realize little trick with bootstrap container class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is PSD(what i  wanna do):[image]
This is HTML:[image]

```css
.bg{
  background:red;
  height:60px;
}
.container{
  max-width:360px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5 bg">
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

*Bg* class is the logo section. Help

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your structure. You have to use `container-fluid` (to go full width) and use `row` inside container like this:

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius:0 50px 50px 0;
}
.content {
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 bg">

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 content">
        the remaining content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `:before` pseudo selector like below

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 360px;
}

.bg:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-5 bg">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove container class to get end to end result and better you use row class

```css
.bg{
  background:red;
  height:60px;
}
.container{
  max-width:360px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 bg">
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: he should not remove container and add row .. both works together, so use them both or remove them both. (as you can see in your code you have overflow due to negative margin of row. And this is corrected with container